# How to make sure that execution of a sync function happens after 3 asynchronous functions are completely done

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

How do I make sure that self.loadable() is executed after all the 3 asynchronous requests are complete. ???

```
var imghtml = "<span class='pull-right' style='padding-right:25px'><img alt='track' src='app/images/Icons/Track.png'><img alt='expand' src='app/images/Icons/Expand.png'></span>";

            var request1 = {};
            if(self.serviceid != null)
                request1.healthIssue = {id:self.serviceid};

            request1.location = {id:self.locationid};
            request1.time = {id:header.defaultduration().value};
            request1.hospital = {id:header.defaulthospital().value};
            request1.query = {groupName:'speciality', dimension:'VISITS', viewBy:'MARKETSHARE'};

            console.log(request1);

            server.fetchData(request1).done(function(data){     

                console.log('The specialty marketshares are : ');
                console.log(data);

                if(data.length != 0) {
                    $.each(data, function(index,mshare){
                        var count = 0;
                        $.each(self.marketsharetable(), function(index, tobj) {
                            if(tobj.specialty == mshare.name){
                                tobj.marketshare(mshare.value);
                                count++;
                                return false;
                            }   
                        });
                        if(count == 0){
                            var obj = {};
                            obj.specialty = mshare.name;
                            obj.marketshare = ko.observable(mshare.value);
                            obj.rank = ko.observable();
                            obj.volume = ko.observable();
                            obj.btns = imghtml;

                            self.marketsharetable.push(obj);
                        }

                    });
                    console.log(self.marketsharetable());
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Clearing the table");
                    $('#msharetable').DataTable({
                        "paging":   false,                  
                        "info":     false,
                        "destroy": true,
                        "data": self.marketsharetable(),
                        "language": {
                            "emptyTable": "No data available"
                        }   
                    });
                }

            });

            var request2 = {};
            if(self.serviceid != null)
                request2.healthIssue = {id:self.serviceid};
            request2.location = {id:self.locationid};
            request2.time = {id:header.defaultduration().value};
            request2.hospital = {id:header.defaulthospital().value};
            request2.query = {groupName:'speciality', dimension:'VISITS', viewBy:'RANK'};           

            server.fetchData(request2).done(function(data){             
                console.log('The specialty ranks are : ');
                console.log(data);

                $.each(data, function(index,mrank){
                    var count = 0;
                    $.each(self.marketsharetable(), function(index, tobj) {
                        if(tobj.specialty == mrank.name){
                            tobj.rank(mrank.value);
                            count++;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    if(count == 0){
                        var obj = {};
                        obj.specialty = mrank.name;
                        obj.marketshare = ko.observable();
                        obj.rank = ko.observable(mrank.value);
                        obj.volume = ko.observable();
                        obj.btns = imghtml;

                        self.marketsharetable.push(obj);
                    }

                });
                console.log(self.marketsharetable());


            });

            var request3 = {};
            if(self.serviceid != null)
                request3.healthIssue = {id:self.serviceid};
            request3.location = {id:self.locationid};
            request3.time = {id:header.defaultduration().value};
            request3.hospital = {id:header.defaulthospital().value};
            request3.query = {groupName:'speciality', dimension:'VISITS', viewBy:'COUNT'};          

            server.fetchData(request3).done(function(data){             
                console.log('The specialty input volumes are : ');
                console.log(data);  


                $.each(data, function(index,mvolume){
                    var count = 0;
                    $.each(self.marketsharetable(), function(index, tobj) {
                        if(tobj.specialty == mvolume.name){
                            tobj.volume(mvolume.value);
                            count++;
                            return false;
                        }   
                    });
                    if(count == 0){
                        var obj = {};
                        obj.specialty = mvolume.name;
                        obj.marketshare = ko.observable();
                        obj.rank = ko.observable();
                        obj.volume = ko.observable(mvolume.value);
                        obj.btns = imghtml;

                        self.marketsharetable.push(obj);
                    }

                });
                console.log(self.marketsharetable());


                $('#msharetable').DataTable({
                    "paging":   false,                  
                    "info":     false,
                    "destroy": true,                    
                    "data": self.marketsharetable(),
                    "language": {
                        "emptyTable": "No data available"
                    },
                    "deferRender": true,
                    "columns": [
                                { "data": "specialty" },
                                { "data": "marketshare" },
                                { "data": "rank" },
                                { "data": "volume" },
                                { "data": "btns" }
                     ]                   
                });

            });
          self.loadtable();
```

Please help how to execute sync function only after 3 asynchronous calls to the server. Am new to advanced javascript. Suggest pls?

Comment: I think you can do this using promises, take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript when you invoke an scynchronous function, it usually returns a promise. As I can see in your code your `server.fetchData(request)` calls return promises, because you use the `.done` which is typicall in promises.

You can store the promise in a variable, like this:

```
var promise1 = server.fetchData(request);
```

And then use it later like this:

```
promise1.done(function() { /* your code here */ });
```

The function inside done will run when the promise is fulfilled. The responsibility for fulfilling (or rejecting) the promise is inside the asynchronous method. I.e. when the request finishes, and the response has arrived, the asynchronous method will fulfill the promise. And, int his case, will fulfill it by providing the response to the callback i.e.

```
promise.done(function(response) { /* use response here */});
```

You can learn more about promises looking at [jQuery docs on deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (which is jQuery way of implementing promise) or googling "javascript promises". A deferred has all the functionality of a `promise`, and also the methods for fulfilling (`resolve`) or rejecting (`reject`) the promise, which can be returned calling the `.promise()` method of the deferred.

For example an asynchronouse method couldlook like this:

```
function asynch() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    // do something asynchronous, and get some data
        // if the result is ok, fulfill the promise
        deferred.resolve(data);
        // if it failed, reject it
        deferred.reject(reason);
    return deferred.promise();
 };
```

The idea is that, if you invoke this method, it will inmediately return a promise. And, when the asynchronous code (like an AJAX call) finishes, the method that returned it will `reject` or `resolve` that promise. When this happens the `done` or `fail` callbacks attached to the promise will be invoked.

Now that you know this basics, jQuery offers a way of composing promises, which is [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). You could write code like this:

```
var promise1 = server.fetchData(request1);
var promise2 = server.fetchData(request2);
var promise3 = server.fetchData(request3);

$.when(promise1, promise2, promise3)
  .done(function(result1, result2, result3) {
     // use the results of the three server.fetchData here
  })
```

The done part will only run if the three promises are fulfilled.If any of them fails, it will not run at all.

You should always handle the `.fail` of your promises. A `server.fetchData` could fail because of several reason, and your code should handle those problems.

There are another interesting promise libraries, [like Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), and they are natively supported in modern browsers: [native promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). They all share the basic concepts, as defined in [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/).

Comment: Thank you JotaBe for a quick and neat answer. @JotaBe